# What is .keras extension?

Tags: keras, computer-vision, vision

I know that we save the Keras models with .h5 extension. But [here](https://github.com/commaai/openpilot/tree/master/models) is some models with .keras extension. Are they Keras models?

Comment: .keras would be a non-standard format, so you should ask the author of that repo on what they actually contain.